# referenced dll suddenly cannot find sql server

Tags: .net-4.5, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016

Its the strangest thing. I have a project that uses a library to call a web service. When the referenced dll is called it fails with :

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Inside the dll its getting the connection string via:

```
string strConnection = global::ThisTroublesomeLibrary.Properties.Settings.Default.prodConnectionString;
```

I have checked the connection string properties they are correct. Also all the other sites including the one calling this library has no problem finding sql server. I have checked the web service that the dll library calls & it seems to be working and returning correct data.

Here is my connection string format:

```
Data Source=mySQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Thedatabaseimtryingtoreach;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=drzounds;Password=itsasecret;
```

I just don't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firewall was blocking the sql connection